# reading a text file to array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a text file `filestoplot.txt` whose structure is like this:

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
```

and I am trying to read this into an array. I tried this:

```
d3.csv("./filestoplot.txt",
    function(file){
         files = file.map(function(d) { 
             for (key in d) { fn=d[key]; } 
             return fn; }
         )
    }
);
```

It looks ok, but I noticed the first line (`file1.csv`) of the inputput file (`filestoplot.txt`) is not being read.

What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `d3.csv` for non-CSV data. Use [`d3.text()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know `d3` very well. I figured out it is a library, but you need to specify what frameworks/libraries you are using in the question.

It is my understanding that you have a `.txt` file and in the file is a list of `.csv` files (one per line) that you want to read in. To do this use ajax, I do not know d3 so I will use jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "./filestoplot.txt",
  success: function(x){
    x = $.trim(x).split("\n"); // Make array from new lines
    /*
      x is now an array that looks like:
      ["file1.csv","file2.csv","file3.csv"]
      do what you want with it here
    */ 
  }
});
```

If I misinterpreted the question let me know in this answers comments and I will attempt to better answer the question. You need to be as specific as possible when asking a question and make sure to state any frameworks/libraries you may be using.